# Kotlin Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'

Tags: firebase, android-studio, kotlin, gradle

I upgraded my android studio version and now I am having this issue. I have tried some couple of solutions that I found(toggle offline mode) but they did not work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved that problem by adding jcenter() to the repositories instead of maven(). It worked well so far but I am not quite sure if it is the correct way.